# Arrays subtraction in Python

Tags: python, numpy

This is my code to implement a linear regression :
But I want to change the last 4 lines to an array subtraction (as it is shown in comment line) I face this error:

```
File "D:/Machine Learning/hw1/hw1-b.py", line 19, in <module>
    gbase = np.matmul(data, cobase)  # h(x)-y matrix
TypeError: Object arrays are not currently supported
```

I look forward to hearing from you

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('C:\Users\Naghme\Desktop\HW1-Data\Data\house2.csv', delimiter=',')
my_data = np.delete(my_data, (0), axis=0)

m=150
z0=0
z1=0
z2=0
z3=0
t=np.zeros((4,1))
a=0.000001
ones=np.ones((150,1))
data=np.append(ones,my_data, axis=1)
for i in range(1,10000):
    cobase = np.append(t,np.array([-1]))
    gbase = np.matmul(data, cobase)  # h(x)-y matrix
    # sigma
    z0 = np.matmul(gbase.transpose(), np.ones((150, 1)))
    z1 = np.matmul(gbase.transpose(), my_data[:, 0])
    z2 = np.matmul(gbase.transpose(), my_data[:, 1])
    z3 = np.matmul(gbase.transpose(), my_data[:, 2])
    z = np.array([z0, z1, z2, z3])
    #delta
    d =np.array( (1.0 / m) * z)
    #t= np.subtract(t,a*d)
    t[0] = t[0] - a * d[0]
    t[1] = t[1] - a * d[1]
    t[2] = t[2] - a * d[2]
    t[3] = t[3] - a * d[3]
```

Best regards

Comment: Please properly format your error in a codeblock

Comment: you mean something like this: https://trinket.io/python3/691c4d578a ? All without numpy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error implies that at least one of the arrays is of type "object"
This could be caused by "mydata" if it is containing any strings.
you should remove all strings from the arrays you need to use the matmul operation on. after that you need to convert them to type float by calling .astype(float). After that matmul should work as expected.

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but it works when I do it element by element as the last 4 lines, this error is just when I want to change it to a array subtraction

Comment: which is why I wrote my answer. the error clearly tells you that one of your array (most likely data) is of type object which is why it does not work. I really think you should give my suggested answer a try ;)

Comment: I think it might work, depending on the type of the current "object". As he stated in my answer,  the output becomes an array itself, so my guess is that it is an array perse

Comment: doing the operation column wise also works because the array gets converted from type object to type float when sliced. 
data (type object) , data[:,0] (gets converted to type float) --> matmul works

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using numpy, you could just do a list comprehension yourself!

```
a = 10
d = [10, 20, 30, 40]
t = [1, 2, 3, 4]

t = [v - a * d[i] for i, v in enumerate(t)]

print(t) # [-99, -198, -297, -396]
```

or use a lambda just for fun:

```
my_substract = lambda v, a, i,: v - a * i

t = [my_substract(v, a, d[i]) for i, v in enumerate(t)]

print(t) # [-99, -198, -297, -396]
```

[Working example](https://trinket.io/python3/5d5d3f1dc9)

Comment: Thanks it works but my output is :[array([0.00814227]), array([0.98023189]), array([0.18691605]), array([0.03326854])] it contains array word.

Comment: Aah nice! Now you are getting output, one of your values (`v` or `d[i]`) is probably a `array`. You should check the values eg. by `print`ing them in your console or using a `trace of pdb` or something